# How to access OneDrive driveItem's properties using Office.js API?

Tags: office-js, onedrive

I am developing Office Word online add-in.

***Use case:*** 
User opens word file from his OneDrive and edits. 
Then user click custom ribbon menu button: "Check-in" added by the add-in.

The check-in handler being implemented in server side should read/pull the respective OneDrive item's file content using Graph API and store in the server vault.

To access the OneDrive item, add-in needs some mechanism to match open file in Office online with respective OneDrive item.

Is there any way to get OneDrive related properties using Office.js API ?
For e.g. does Office.context.document.url property value same as OneDrive item's webUrl property ?
Is there any other suggestion to implement such functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a driveitem object by using the /shares Graph api.

Comment: Thanks Jakob, I am looking for some mechanism to match open file in Office online with respective OneDrive item